# Python pillow/PIL doesn't recognize the attribute "textsize" of the object "imagedraw"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I already checked python version on my environment (sublime text) and it is 3.11.0, the latest, I checked pillow version which is 10.0.0, the latest, and my code looks similar to other examples online.

the code has a part in Italian, but its pretty understandable.

the problem is at "disegno.textsize(testo, font=font)

after I run the code:

```
line 14, in metti_testo_su_sfondo
    text_width, text_height = disegno.textsize(testo, font=font)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'
```

its strange because imagedraw should have the textsize attribute. I'm a novice, I hope I didn't miss anything blatant

---

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def metti_testo_su_sfondo(testo, sfondo, posizione=(10, 10), colore_testo=(0, 0, 0), dimensione_font=25):
# Apri l'immagine dello sfondo
immagine_sfondo = Image.open(sfondo)


disegno = ImageDraw.Draw(immagine_sfondo)


font = ImageFont.truetype("ARIAL.TTF", dimensione_font)


text_width, text_height = disegno.textsize(testo, font=font)

# Calcola le coordinate del testo centrato
x = (immagine_sfondo.width - text_width) // 2
y = (immagine_sfondo.height - text_height) // 2


disegno.text((x, y), testo, fill=colore_testo, font=font)


immagine_sfondo.save("spotted.png")


testo_da_inserire = "Ciao, mondo!"
sfondo_da_utilizzare = "spotted_bianco.jpg" 

metti_testo_su_sfondo(testo_da_inserire, sfondo_da_utilizzare)
```

The objective is a code that makes me images automatically without needing to edit them manually. I checked build system, python version and pillow version. when I run the code through cmd though it gives me this error:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: You are probably not using the Python version into which you installed `Pillow`. Try adding this at the start of your script to see which Python you are actually running `import sys; print(sys.executable, sys.version, *sys.path, sep="\n")` Then, outside of your IDE, check where you installed `Pillow`

Comment: thank you Mark, but unfortunately i dont think i solved anything.
C:\Python311\python.exe 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48)
 [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\text files\spotted 
C:\Python311\python311.zip C:\Python311\Lib C:\Python311\DLLs 
C:\Python311 C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vboxapi-1.0-py3.11.egg
 python seems to be the right version, i also updated my build system the same day pillow is installed in python311\lib\site-packages C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Pillow-10.0.0.dist-info

Comment: i think i will try to uninstall and reinstall pillow, then ill try with a virtual machine

Comment: i also tried using the textsize attribute in another code just to make sure
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

b = Image.open("spotted_bianco.jpg")

a = ImageDraw.Draw(b)

c, d = a.textsize("e", font="ARIAL.TTF")

i tried running it

  c, d = a.textsize("e", font="ARIAL.TTF")
           ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'
[Finished in 161ms]

and ofc it didnt work

Comment: i solved it. i decided to run it on a kali vm, and it told me that in pillow 10, the most recent version wich came out 7 days ago, textsize was going to be deprecated. ill fix my code, thank you for helping me.

Comment: once i solve my problem will moderators mark it as solved or do i need to do something? i cant find a "mark as solved" button anywhere

Comment: @carokann17 Please write an Answer (form is below) with the solution and detailing the steps you took to fix your code. After a period of time you will be able to mark it as the correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

textsize was deprecated, the correct attribute is textlength which gives you the width of the text. for the height use the fontsize * how many rows of text you wrote.

Comment: provide example code please

Answer (score 3):

It's no longer called `textsize`, it's called `textlength`.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have mentioned, `textsize` is deprecated.
There is no textheight, but you can use `textlength`.

If you just want a function that can test a given `text` and `font` pair, you can do something like this with `textbbox`:

```py
def textsize(text, font):
    im = Image.new(mode="P", size=(0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    _, _, width, height = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text=text, font=font)
    return width, height
```

Which should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pillow==9.5.0

version=9.5.0
```

It can still be used, but a warning will appear
Use textbbox or textlength instead.

```
  c_width, c_height = draw.textsize(c, font=font)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the font.getbbox(text) and it will returned a 4 element tuple (x1,y1,x2,y2)

width , heigth = (x2-x1, y2-y1)